# How did (2+1) KP equation derived from Sato theory?

Tags: integrable-systems, soliton-theory

In section "Connection with Sato theory" of webpage [scholarpedia](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Kadomtsev-Petviashvili_equation) they discussed that KP equation can be derived from taking a pseudo-differential operator $L$ and consider the differential equation $dL/dt_m=[(L^m)_{+},L]$. So how did this carried out? Especially what's the relationship between $L$ and $u$?

Comment: I found an explanation in Chapter3 of "Tau Functions and their Applications". But still unclear to me: the initial condition is a function on real line, but for this case the initial condition is a function on plane, there must be some relaxation and I'm not sure why it is meaningful